# Can I wear a Pentagram T-shirt?

Tags: clothing, avodah-zarah

Can I wear a T-shirt with a 5 sided pentagram on it? It's usually associated with Wiccans/Satan so it's seems like there might be some kind of issur here, though I can't think of one.

Comment: I’ll leave Avodah Zarah 42b up for grabs. For sure that’s the main sugya to answer this from, but I don’t have time right now to go through the poskim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A comparable Shaila is if one can wear a shirt with a cross on it, if the cross was not printed "Leshem Avodah Zarah".  See [here](https://www.hidabroot.org/question/128511), [here](https://www.hidabroot.org/question/77120), [here](https://www.yeshiva.org.il/ask/86995), [here](http://www.kipa.co.il/%D7%A9%D7%90%D7%9C-%D7%90%D7%AA-%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%91/%D7%A6%D7%9C%D7%91-%D7%91%D7%91%D7%92%D7%93/) and [here](https://www.yeshiva.org.il/ask/74022), which are Matir this according to the technical Halacha, but suggest that it is inappropriate.  Therefore, this is Halachically appropriate to wear in terms of Hilchos Avodah Zarah according to the Poskim quoted above.

Comment: Is a pentagram considered a symbol of Avodah Zarah, though?

Comment: @DonielF אפילו אם תמצא לומר...

Comment: While a symbol not put on there for idolatrous reasons is technically okay, you still note that one should avoid it. Does that same hesitation apply to a pentagram, or is there no issue even from the outset?

Comment: @DonielF The OP asked for any Issurim, I showed that there was no Issur of Avodah Zarah.  The reason I added the "inappropriate" was in order to not to misquote/misrepresent those articles, but I did not conclude whether or not it wearing **this shirt** is considered inappropriate. But that is an interesting point, perhaps ask it as a separate question (something like "According to Judaism, is it inappropriate to wear a shirt with such and such a symbol on it?").